# Nested loop error: incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Tags: r

I have a table with ELISA results with samples in rows and assays quantifying signals from 75 different antibodies in columns. I now want to know which markers correlate with each other across the whole dataset with which p-value and fdr.

Doing it one by one for single columns works:

```
pvalues_IL17A <- c()

for (i in 1:ncol(data1)){
pvalues_IL17A[i] <- cor.test(data1[,i], data1$IL.17A, 
method="spearman")$p.value
}
```

OR

```
pvalues_IL17A <- c()

for (i in 1:ncol(data1)){
pvalues_IL17A[i] <- cor.test(data1[,i], data1$IL.17A, 
method="spearman")$estimate
}
```

I tried to make a nested loop, as I don't want to run the code 75 times e.g. for the pvalues:

```
pvalues <- c()

for (i in 1:ncol(data1)){
for (j in 1:ncol(data1)){
pvalues[i,j] <- cor.test(as.matrix(data1[,i]), as.matrix(data1[,j]), 
method="spearman")$p.value
}}
```

But it's not working:
Error in pvalues[i, j] <- cor.test(as.matrix(data1[, i]), as.matrix(data1[,  :
    incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Can anyone spot the error? I would expect a matrix with all assays in rows as well as columns with the p-values for significant correlation. Where the assay is the same in the col and row the value should be 0.

I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: You are initializing a vector and then subsetting it like a matrix. Initialize like this: pvalues <- matrix(nrow = ncol(data1), ncol = ncol(data1))

Comment: Yes, of course. It was a remnant of the previous code that I did not pay attention to. Thank you so much! How could I include the column names from data1 as column names and rownames in the pvalues matrix?